# Magento Module - Second group not displaying

Tags: xml, magento, module

This is my first attempt at building a module however, something in the below group `<categorylog>` is broken. The first group `<productlog>` works fine. So far this creates a new tab in System->Configuration called Frank with a Section called proper log. Can anyone see what is wrong with  group ?

```
<config>
<tabs>
    <frank>
        <label>Frank</label>
        <sort_order>100</sort_order>
    </frank>
</tabs>
<sections>
    <properlog>
        <tab>frank</tab>
        <class>separator-top</class>
        <label>Proper Log</label>
        <sort_order>100</sort_order>
        <show_in_default>1</show_in_default>
        <show_in_website>1</show_in_website>
        <show_in_store>1</show_in_store>

        <groups>
            <productlog>
                <label>Product Logs</label>
                <frontend_type>text</frontend_type>
                <show_in_default>1</show_in_default>
                <show_in_website>1</show_in_website>
                <show_in_store>1</show_in_store>
                <sort_order>100</sort_order>
                <fields>
                    <product_logs_enabled>
                        <label>Enable Product Logs</label>
                        <comment>Set to yes to log product updates</comment>
                        <frontend_type>select</frontend_type>
                        <source_model>adminhtml/system_config_source_yesno</source_model>
                        <show_in_default>1</show_in_default>
                        <show_in_website>1</show_in_website>
                        <show_in_store>1</show_in_store>
                        <sort_order>10</sort_order>
                    </product_logs_enabled>

                    <attributes_to_track>
                        <label>Attributes to Track</label>
                        <frontend_type>textarea</frontend_type>
                        <comment>comma deliminated list of product attribues (eg. type,name,box_width)</comment>
                        <show_in_default>1</show_in_default>
                        <show_in_website>1</show_in_website>
                        <show_in_store>1</show_in_store>
                        <sort_order>20</sort_order>
                    </attributes_to_track>
                </fields>
            </productlog>

            <categorylog>
                <label>Category Logs</label>
                <frontend_type>text</frontend_type>
                <show_in_default>1</show_in_default>
                <show_in_website>1</show_in_website>
                <show_in_store>1</show_in_store>
                <sort_order>200</sort_order>
                <fields>
                    <category_logs_enabled>
                        <label>Enable Category Logs</label>
                        <comment>Set to yes to log category updates</comment>
                        <frontend_type>select</frontend_type>
                        <source_model>adminhtml/system_config_source_yesno</source_model>
                        <sort_order>10</sort_order>
                    </category_logs_enabled>
                </fields>
            </categorylog>

        </groups>
    </properlog>
</sections>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are missing the `show_in` values; the default behavior is to *not* show:

```
<sections>
    <properlog>
        <groups>
            <categorylog>
                <fields>
                    <category_logs_enabled>
                        <label>Enable Category Logs</label>
                        <comment>Set to yes to log category updates</comment>
                        <frontend_type>select</frontend_type>
                        <source_model>adminhtml/system_config_source_yesno</source_model>
                        <sort_order>10</sort_order>
                        <!-- add these -->
                        <show_in_default>1</show_in_default>
                        <show_in_website>1</show_in_website>
                        <show_in_store>1</show_in_store>
                    </category_logs_enabled>
                </fields>
            </categorylog>
        </groups>
    </properlog>
</sections>
```

Comment: Yeah i realised this later on. But you know how it is when you have been looking at something for too long. Thanks!